# how does log4j log complete error stack

Tags: log4j

I am using `log4j` to log the errors and I find the error details is omitted like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
        ... 18 more
```

How could I see the whole error stack instead of the `18 more`?

My `log4j.properties` is like this:

```
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console, LOGFILE

# Direct log messages to console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Direct log messages to a log LOGFILE
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=/home/di_yu/aap/services/spark/logs/spark.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have used

```
LOGGER.error("Exception generated ",  ex.getMessage());
```

just use

```
 LOGGER.error("Exception generated ",  ex);
```

it will log whole stack trace.